# How to use genenric class as parameter in IHandle<> from caliburn.micro?

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I try to get the following thing working with no success. :-( I want to use a generic class as a parameter for the `IHandle<>` interface. Here is the sample code:

```
public interface Message<T>
{ 
    T Payload { get; set; }
}

...

public MyViewModel : Screen, IHandle<IMessage<T>>
{
    ...
    public void Handle(IMessage<T> message)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

The question is: How do I declare the IHandle in a correct way? Or do I need to specify for each `T` it own `IHandle` and `Handle()`?

Think I have just a block in my mind since I try to solve this since hours and due to the fact that I'm on the best way getting crazy.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: To show what I want to do I added two possible but not very nice solutions.

Possible solution 1:

```
public MyViewModel : Screen, IHandle<IMessage<String>>, IHandle<IMessage<Int32>>
```

and so on. The problem with this is, that I always need to edit the ViewModel when a new `T` should be supported. In this case I could skip the generic `IMessage` and create specific messages (like `IStringMessage`, `IInt32Message`) which would make the code more readable, but couples it with each type used.

Possible solution 2:

```
public MyViewModel : Screen, IHandle<IMessage>
```

And change `IMessage` to:

```
public interface IMessage
{ 
    Object Payload { get; set; }
}
```

This could do the job, but I loose the typesafty of the `Payload`. Optional a `TypeOfPayload` property could be added, but also not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you need to provide generic parameter to `IHandle<>` when implementing it in `MyViewModel` ? If not , why not simply do `IHandler<Message<ConcreteType>>` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far, but I cannot make the viewmodel itself generic. I just want to have the messages handled to be generic and I try to avoid to have a method for each <T>.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for these requirements:

1) You need a message for a given type, like a "message of person"

2) You need a handler for a given type and its messages, like "handler of person"

You can write the interfaces like this:

```
public interface IHandle<T>
{
    void Handle(IMessage<T> message);
}
public interface IMessage<T>
{
    T Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response too. But I need a handler for generic messages. I updated the question to describe the problem in a better way.

Comment: But this handler is already for generic messages (of type `T`). What requirement of yours is not captured by this solution?

Comment: No, the handler is for type `Message<T>` and not of `T`. And the `IHandle` interface is defined by Caliburn.Micro. Both of your assumptions are not the things I want to do. So I added new info to my question. Thanks for your reply! I require the method to be too generic I thing, it should be able to handle `Message<T>` without specifing the `T` in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Please check;

```
interface IHandle<T>
    {
        T Handle { get; set; }
    }
    public interface Message<T>
    {
        T Payload { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyViewModel <T>: IHandle<T>
    {
        public T Handle { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
```

if you need to create instance of MyViewModel:

```
MyViewModel<YourClassName> model=new MyViewModel<YourClassName>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesn't do the trick. The `IHandle` is defined by Caliburn.Micro and the handler shall handle `Message<T>` not `T`.